# Why do I keep receiving a "fatal error" when trying to fetch a UILabel for my UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I'm a beginner coder and I've hit a seeming impasse. I'm setting up a `UITableView` to display blog posts from users. I can successfully retrieve information from my Firestore database, but am having trouble actually populating this information into my `UITableViewCell`. I think this is down to the way my 'PostTableViewCell' is set up. Any answers to this would be immensely appreciated. Here is what I have:

**Home View Controller:**

```
 var postArray: [String] = []
var documents: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

let db = Firestore.firestore()
let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    // Find the UserIDs of people following
// Where Field for those UserIDs in "Posts"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getFollowingPosts()
    configureTableView()
    }

func getFollowingPosts() {
    let searchForFollowing = db.collection("users").document(currentUserID!).collection("Following")
    searchForFollowing.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        for documents in snapshot!.documents {
            let followedUID = documents.get("uid")
            print(followedUID!)
            
            self.db.collection("posts").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: followedUID!).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                for documents in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let uid = documents.get("uid") as! String
                    let title = documents.get("Title") as! String
                    let ProfilePictureURL = documents.get("ProfilePictureURL") as! String
                    let username = documents.get("username") as! String
                    let content = documents.get("Content") as! String
                    self.postArray.append(title)
                    print(self.postArray)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    }

func configureTableView() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(PostTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PostCell")

    // remove separators for empty cells
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    // remove separators from cells
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    postArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    let post = postArray[indexPath.row]
    **cell.titleLabel.text = post** //Error is encountered here
    return cell
}
```

**PostTableViewCell:**

```
class PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var contentLabel: UILabel!
}
```

As I said in the title, I keep receiving a 'Fatal Error: unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" whenever I try to build, leading me to believe something is wrong with my 'PostTableViewCell' - this point is marked with double asterisks in my code. Any information and answers would be massively appreciated. I'm a real beginner, and eager to progress from this standstill.

[image]

Comment: Did you create your cell in storyboard or by code? Also, can you post the entire code for PostTableviewCell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the following statement from your code:

```
    tableView.register(PostTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PostCell")
```

2. You are missing this function inside PostTableViewCell:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your response. Sorry for all the questions (especially that they're so basic), would I initialise my cell with init()?

Comment: No worries. You initialize it with the code I posted which is two init functions that you need to override inside your tableViewCell code. Did you create your cell programmatically, using storyboard, or a xib file?

Comment: I seem to still be getting the same error, in the same place, with the new code. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: In this case, you don't really need to register your cell if the cell was added to tableView inside storyboard. I'm guessing that your issue probably has to do with you not linking your IBOutlet properly. Can you double check that your IBOutlets are properly connected?

Comment: Everything seems to be fine there. I'll upload a screenshot to my question, in case I've got something wrong, but, the connections seem to be fine

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it doesn't work out, please do add a couple screenshots.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, it's still not working. I'm getting the same error. I noticed that you originally asked for me to upload more of my code from my PostTableViewCell. But, that's all I had at the time. Is there something boilerplate I'm missing?

Comment: Did you remove the register cell statement and kept the awakeFromNib()? Also, make sure to set the cell ID in storyboard.

Comment: I removed the register cell statement, and now it doesn't crash with an error - instead, it just doesn't show anything.

Comment: I'm assuming that it's working now since you validated my answer?

Comment: Yes absolutely! I tried again, tweaking a few things, and all is working out! Thank you so much for your help!